# Remove mysqld from autostart

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, autostart

I installed mysql via Homebrew using these instructions http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion.

I also added it to the auto-start by using these commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/com.mysql.mysqld.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Since it takes up a lot of RAM I'd like to remove it from the auto-start but don't know how to accomplish this. **How can I remove mysqld from the autostart?**

`launchtl list | grep mysql` only gives these entries which can't be removed

> 4104  -   homebrew.mxcl.mysql
>
> 4317  -   0x7f90704148e0.anonymous.mysqld

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Or just remove the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist` file.

Answer (score 11):

If you installed mysql using brew/homebrew, then remove using

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me with mysql `8.0.12` installed using Homebrew in `macOS Mojave 10.14.1`.

Comment: this is up to date answer

Comment: Running `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` will shutdown the process for you as well.